# How to deal with org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class that looks like

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ClientRegistrationManager {
    private CrudService crudService;
    private UniqueIdGenerator uniqueIdGenerator;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public ClientRegistrationManager() {
    }

    @Inject
    public ClientRegistrationManager(@Nonnull final CrudService crudService, @Nonnull final UniqueIdGenerator uniqueIdGenerator) {
        this.crudService = crudService;
        this.uniqueIdGenerator = uniqueIdGenerator;
    }

    public Member register(@Nonnull final String email, @Nonnull final String userExternalId, @Nonnull final String password) {
        final Member existingMember;
        try {
            existingMember = getMemberQueries().getMemberByEmail(email);
        } catch (final NoResultException e) {
            return createNewMemberAndGetClientDetail(email, userExternalId);
        }
        return existingMember;
    }

    ...

    @Nonnull
    protected MemberQueries getMemberQueries() {
        return new MemberQueries(crudService);
    }
}
```

I wanted to test it by mocking out any external behavior, so I created `getMemberQueries()` using Pattern - 1 described in [doc](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation)

I, then write my test as following

```
public class ClientRegistrationManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private MemberQueries memberQueries;

    @Mock
    private CrudService crudService;

    @Mock
    private UniqueIdGenerator uniqueIdGenerator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockedMemberQueries() {
        final ClientRegistrationManager clientRegistrationManager = new ClientRegistrationManager(crudService, uniqueIdGenerator);
        Mockito.when(clientRegistrationManager.getMemberQueries()).thenReturn(memberQueries);
        clientRegistrationManager.getMemberQueries();
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error as

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

Now what it means I need to mock out the entire `ClientRegistrationManager`, but that the class I want to test, I can not just mock that entire class.

I am trying to understand my options here, I really do not want to depend on `persistence` layer, that will be too heavy

Comment: Well, you are creating an instance of `ClientRegistrationManager` yourself - so it is no mock - but then passing it to `when`. I think, the message is very clear: "when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'". Mocks should only be created for the dependencies of the class under test.

Comment: Yes @Seelenvirtuose, I understand that. I am looking for ideas on how to mock `new Object()` created inside class under test

Comment: This comes down to one question: _Why mock the class under test?_

Comment: I do not want to do that, I want to mock the `new Object()` creation for the class under test

Comment: Hmmm ... I do no understand. Maybe the bigger picture is necessary here. Could you describe more? In fact, it never should be necessary to mock the class under test, and it never should be necessary to setup results on method calls of a mocked instance of the class under test (like you did).

Comment: Okay, let me explain, I want to test `ClientRegistrationManager` and I do **not** want to mock it. but in that class I use `new MemberQueries(crudService)` which is an external dependency on persistence layer, I want to mock that behavior, did you get it now?

Comment: Ah! That's clear. So in fact, this is a design issue! Such dependencies should be expressed in interfaces. Your `ClientRegistrationManager` should depend on an interface `QueriesFactory` (for example), for which a `MemberQueriesFactory` class could be an implementation. Now you can mock the interface and simply test your class. This is the whole essence of mocking! (Side note: This leads to better designs.)

Comment: and how do you intend to use `QueriesFactory` in `ClientRegistrationManager`? you would use `new QueriesFactory`, right? if yes then problem remains same. If no, please let me know how

Comment: Your class `ClientRegistrationManager` should depend on a `QueriesFactory`, but should not create it. The keyword here is "dependency injection". The manager's conctructor must be given such a factory. In your program, you create a manager with a `MemberQueriesFactory` that produces real `MemberQueries`. The test can mock the factory, so you have everything in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose) is correct in the comments: The root problem is that you can only call `when` on mocks and spies, and that it is typically an anti-pattern to mock the class-under-test.

One technique is to use `spy`, which lets you intercept and verify calls to a real object ("partial mocking"):

```
final ClientRegistrationManager clientRegistrationManager =
    Mockito.spy(new ClientRegistrationManager(crudService, uniqueIdGenerator);
// doReturn is important because the call to contains a call to the mock
// before Mockito has intercepted it. In your case, this may just create a useless
// real MemberQueries, but in other cases it can throw an exception.
Mockito.doReturn(memberQueries).when(clientRegistrationManager).getMemberQueries();
```

As [Predrag Magic wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609722/1426891), another way to do this is to create a factory and replace that during the test. This is especially good if you pass in the factory as an optional constructor argument, because then production systems could create and pass in their own MemberQueryFactory and your class would still work as expected.

```
public class ClientRegistrationManager {
  static class MemberQueriesFactory {
    MemberQueries getMemberQueries() {
      return ObjectFactory.newMemberQueries(crudService);
    }
  }

  /** Package-private. Visible for unit testing. */
  MemberQueriesFactory memberQueriesFactory = new MembersQueryFactory();
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientRegistrationManagerTest {
  @Mock ClientRegistrationManager.MembersQueryFactory mockMembersQueryFactory;

  private ClientRegistrationManager getManagerForTest() {
    ClientRegistrationManager manager = new ClientRegistrationManager();
    manager.memberQueriesFactory = mockMembersQueryFactory;
    return manager;
  }
}
```

My favorite way, though, is to skip Mockito and directly override the class-under-test in the test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientRegistrationManagerTest {
  @Mock MemberQueries memberQueries;

  private ClientRegistrationManager getManagerForTest() {
    ClientRegistrationManager manager = new ClientRegistrationManager() {
      @Override void getMemberQueries() {
        return memberQueries;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of spy since they are not too intrusive plus I do not have to write too much code to test

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use some kind of object factory to create new objects in classes under test, and then mock that factory.

```
protected MemberQueries getMemberQueries() {
    return ObjectFactory.newMemberQueries(crudService);
}
```

If, for some reason, you want to mock just selected methods of some object instead of the whole object, you can do that with Mockito. Check out [this](http://blog.javabien.net/2009/06/21/mockitos-partial-mocks-testing-real-objects-just-got-easier/) example.